# Find the mean of one variable subseted by another variable

Tags: r, function, select

I have a list of identical dataframes. Each data frame contains columns with unique variables (temp/DO) and with repeated variables (eg-t1).

```
[[1]]
    temp DO t1 
    1    4  1
    3    9  1
    5    7  1
```

I want to find the mean of DO when the temperature is equal to t1. 
t1 represents a specific temperature, but the value varies for each data frame in the list so I can't specify an actual value.

So far I've tried writing a function

```
    hvod<-function(DO, temp, depth){
      hDO<-DO[which(temp==t1[1])]
      mHDO<-mean(hDO)
      htemp<-temp[which(temp=t1[1])]
      mhtemp<-mean(htemp)
}

hfit<-hvod(data$DO, data$temp, data$depth)
```

But for whatever reason t1 is not recognized. Any ideas on the function OR
a way to combine select (dplyr function) and lapply to solve this? 
I've seen similar posts put none that apply to the issue of a specific value (t1) that changes for each data frame.

Comment: `t1` is not an R object. It is only a character value that can reference the third column of `data`. You could try `temp====data$t1[1]`. It's kind of ugly code but would find a value. You should present `dput(data)` if you want a better answer. The display of the data object suggests it might be nested in another named object.

Comment: You are passing data$depth as depth to the function but it is neither used anywhere inside the function nor is printed in [[1]] dataframe. Did you mean to pass data$t1 instead and capture it as t1? Like, hvod<-function(DO, temp, t1) and hfit<-hvod(data$DO, data$temp, data$t1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Thiloshon and MKR for the help! I had initial combined the data I needed into one list of data frames but to answer this I actually had my data in separate data frames (`fitsObs` and `df1`).
The variables I was working with in the code were 1 to 1, so by finding the range where `depth` and `d2` were the same (I used `temp` and `t1` in the example), I could find the mean over that range .

```
for(i in 1:1044){
  df1 <- GLNPOsurveyCTD$data[[i]]

 fitObs <- fitTp2(-df1$depth, df1$temp)  

  deptho <- -abs(df1$depth)       #defining temp and depth in the loop
  to <- df1$temp
  do <- df1$DO

xx <- which(deptho <= fitObs$d2)      #mean over range xx
  mhtemp <-  mean(to[xx], na.rm=TRUE)
  mHDO <-  mean(do[xx], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the dataframe as argument and do rest of the logic inside function as it gives more control to the function. Something like this would work,

```
 hvod<-function(data){
      temp <- data$temp
      t1 <- data$t1
      DO <- data$DO

      hDO<-DO[which(temp==t1[1])]
      mHDO<-mean(hDO)
      htemp<-temp[which(temp=t1[1])]
      mhtemp<-mean(htemp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `dplyr::bind_rows` function to combine all data.frames from list in one data.frame.

Then group on data.frame number to find the `mean` of `DO` for rows having `temp==t1` as:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(ll, .id = "DF_Name") %>%
  group_by(DF_Name) %>%
  filter(temp==t1) %>%
  summarise(MeanDO = mean(DO)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   DF_Name MeanDO
# 1       1    4.0
# 2       2    6.5
# 3       3    6.7
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 
"temp DO t1 
1    4  1
3    9  1
5    7  1",
header = TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text = 
"temp DO t1 
3    4  3
3    9  3
5    7  1",
header = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = 
"temp DO t1 
2    4  2
2    9  2
2    7  2",
header = TRUE)

ll <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```